# Why review compositing work in MJPEG videos rather than (say) H.264?

Tags: colors, ffmpeg, video-encoding, mjpeg

I have received a request to encode DPX files to MOV/MJPEG rather than MOV/H.264 (which ffmpeg picks by default if you convert to `output.mov`). These is to review [compositing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_compositing) renders (in motion), so color accuracy is critical.

Comparing a sample "ideal" MOV to the current (H.264) output I can see:

- resolution: the same
- ColorSpace/Primaries: Rec609 (SD) versus Rec709 (HD)
- YUV: 4:2:0 versus 4:4:4
- filesize: smaller

The ffmpeg default seems to be better quality and result in a smaller filesize. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's because MJPEG frames are independent of each other, so any snippet of video can be decoded / copied in isolation.  With an inter-frame compression algorithm like H.264, the software has to scan data for potentially numerous frames to reconstruct any given one.